# Change diodes in a NAD C326BEE audio amplifier

Tags: amplifier, diodes, zener

After reading this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/431760/can-a-zener-diode-with-a-higher-power-dissipation-be-used-in-place-of-the-origin), I have additional questions:

I have a NAD CEE326BEE amplifier which is +10 year old. Since 1 week, when I try to switch it on, there is a click and nothing else happens.

According to what I've found in different sources, this might be related to the protection circuit which is switching it off at startup.

I've inspected the board visually and I have found 3 diodes which were not soldered properly, it looks like they are producing heat which has damaged theirs soldering points:

[image: Boad Photo]

According to the electronic shema these are the following:

[image: Electronic schema]

The diodes described in the [NAD C326BEE Service Manual](https://elektrotanya.com/nad_c326bee.pdf/download.html) are the following:

- Diode 1N4007 DO-41 1A/1000V (RoHS) **D136**
- DIODE ZENER 5.1V 3W 5% DO-41 1N5918B (RoHS) **D134 / D135**

I'm not able to find replacement components which the exact same specifications.

**Questions:**

- What would be a good replacements (I've read that higher wattage Zeners could be a good fit?)
- What could be improved to prevent future overheating?

Comment: *I'm not able to find replacement components which the exact same specifications.* Then you're doing something wrong as these are very common components. Go to mouser.com and type "1N4007" or "1N5918B" in the search box. Both searches give plenty of hits.

Comment: 1N5918B and 1N4007 are still available as far as I know. The regulator 7805 is rated for max 30V input, that is probably the reason  those zeners are used in that position. @Bimpelrekkie, my first hit was also at Mouser.

Comment: *What could be improved to prevent future overheating ?* Not much, they need to dissipate the energy so they get hot. What you can do is give the zeners enough "breathing space" so keep the leads somewhat longer and bend the leads such that air can freely pass the zeners.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie, you are right. I noticed it after reading my comment. I meant linear regulator of course.

Comment: @Kami, if you can't find these diodes you could maybe replace it with a simple BJT circuit that lowers the input voltage to the regulator to a safe value.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks a lot for you feedback. I've done the same search at mouser.com but for the 1N5918B, the results are showing zeners with a power dissipation of 1.25W and 1.5W. According to the schema they should have a PD of 3W. Am I wrong ?

Comment: No you're right, my guess is that the 1N5918B **is** a 1.5 W zener and that the "3W" in the schematic is **wrong**. Also comparing the size of the 1N5918B to the 1N4007, the 1N5918B isn't much larger. If the 1N5918B really was rated for 3 W it would have to be **much larger**. There's a 3 W zener: 1N5919 but there is no 5.1 V version of that. You could just use two 5.6 V (instead of 5.1 V), there is still plenty of "headroom" for the 7805.

Comment: So your solutions:  1) buy 2x 1N5918, 5.1 V, 1.5 W and assume that the "3W" isn't true. or 2) buy 2x 1N5919, 5.6 V, 3W, that will slightly decrease the voltage to the 7805 but that should be no issue. In any case: mount the zeners with long leads so that they can "breathe". I would choose solution 2) btw, it is a bit more robust.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Thanks a lot for your extensive explaination. I've went for solution 2). As stated initially in my question, I haven't found components with the same specifications du to that mislead of the 3W. Would you like to make your last comment as an answer ? Thanks

Comment: Your picture doesn't show the solder joint.  What it shows is a board with holes that are not plated through; the solder joint would exist only on the reverse side, and not through the board and on top as it would with plated through holes.

Comment: Interestingly, I saw a comment by Olin Lathrop to a question about regulators (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93330/using-a-zener-diode-to-ease-a-voltage-regulator/93378#comment1343883_93378)
I think he has a valid point that under no load condition the zeners would drop a too low voltage so the input of the regulator could still be above maximum rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What could be improved to prevent future overheating ?

Not much, they need to dissipate the energy so they get hot. What you can do is give the zeners enough "breathing space" so keep the leads somewhat longer and bend the leads such that air can freely pass the zeners.

> ...zeners with a power dissipation of 1.25W and 1.5W

Indeed, the 1N5918B is a 1.5 W zener and that the "3W" in the schematic is probably wrong. Also comparing the size of the 1N5918B to the 1N4007, the 1N5918B isn't much larger and the 1N4007 also has a maximum dissipation of around 1 W. If the 1N5918B really was rated for 3 W it would have to be much larger and/or need a (small) heatsink!

3 W zeners do exist, the [1N5919](https://nl.mouser.com/Search/Refine?Keyword=1N5919) but there is no 5.1 V version of that. You could just use two 5.6 V (instead of 5.1 V), there is still plenty of "headroom" for the 7805.

So your solutions:

1. buy 2x 1N5918, 5.1 V, 1.5 W and assume that the "3W" isn't true.

or

2. buy 2x 1N5919, 5.6 V, 3W, that will slightly decrease the voltage to the 7805 but that should be no issue. In any case: mount the zeners with long leads so that they can "breathe".

I would choose solution 2) btw, it is a bit more robust.

Comment: Many thanks for everything!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to better cool those 3 diodes, then remove the white sleeves on the leads.

Then install a tiny fan. Or drill holes in bottom of chassis, for air flow.